# ¿No puedo obtener la ruta de mi carpeta compartida en el servidor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, epplus

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Estoy leyendo un excel desde una carpeta compartida cuando lo ejecuto desde la aplicación(Local) obtiene los datos del excel pero al subir al servidor no lee la carpeta compartida.

Otra manera fue crear una carpeta en C: de mi servidor pero tampoco lee el archivo.

Le paso la ruta

```
LeerExcel(@"C:\liquidaciones_lcl_charter\" + model.HBL);
```

Código

```
public HtmlString LeerExcel(string filePath)
        {
            FileInfo rutaFile = new FileInfo(filePath+".xlsx");

            var estructuraHTML = "<table class='table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed flip-content'><tbody>";
            if (rutaFile.Exists)
            {
                using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(rutaFile))
                {
                    //get the first worksheet in the workbook
                    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
                    int colCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;  //get Column Count
                    int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;     //get row count
                    for (int row = 1; row <= rowCount; row++)
                    {
                        estructuraHTML += "<tr>";
                        for (int col = 1; col <= colCount; col++)
                        {
                           estructuraHTML += "<td>" + worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value?.ToString().Trim() + "</td>";

                        }
                        estructuraHTML += "</tr>";
                    }
                    estructuraHTML += "</tbody></table>";
                }
            }
            
            else
            {
                estructuraHTML = "";
            }

            return new HtmlString(estructuraHTML);
            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Si hablamos de un entorno ASP.NET MVC, la aplicación corre bajo un IIS, con lo cuál tenes que hablitarle el acceso a esa carpeta y aprovechar lo nativo de esto.

Para dar acceso a carpetas del serivdor se usan [Directorios Virtuales](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/create-virtual-directory-folder-remote-computer).

Luego en tu aplicación accedes directamente al directorio (IIS te resuelve la ruta física) y para esto normalmente se usa el concepto de Mapper que básicamente es un servicio que se encarga de "mapearte" lo que necesites.

En cierto punto deberías tener un controlador con código similar a este:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubirArchivo(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    file.SaveAs(_pathMapper.RutaArchivosXLS + "nombreArchivo");
}
```

Y el Mapper podría ser algo así:

```
public class WebPathMapper
{
    public string MapPath(string virtualPath)
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + virtualPath);
    }

    public string RutaArchivosXLS
    {
        get { return MapPath("CarpetaConArchviosXLS"); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cuando hago HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath me tira error CS1061, 'HttpContext' no contiene una definición para 'Current' y no se pudo encontrar ningún método de extensión accesible 'nombre' que acepte un primer argumento de tipo 'tipo' (¿falta una directiva de uso o una referencia de ensamblado?). que using hace falta o nugget? El VS no me da ninguna recomendacion.

Comment: @BilbitBolson habría que ver desde dónde estás llamando al Mapper, lo normal en un entorno ASP.NET MVC es que tengas HttpContext.

Te dejo este link que tal vez te ayude: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431820/system-web-httpcontextbase-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-current-mvc-4-wi